# Port Forwarding Between 2 Internet Machines

Tags: iptables, firewall, port-forwarding

Here's my scenario:

### Setup

There are 3 machines:

`A`: on the internet : has ip (`a.a.a.a`), has port `pa` open

`B`: my server / gateway : has ip (`b.b.b.b`), has port `pb` open

`C`: on the internet : has ip (`c.c.c.c`), has port `pc` open

### Constraints

The owner of machine `A` offers a service via port `pa` that must be accessed on machine `C` via port `pc`. The problem is, the owner of `A` can only allow to directly connect with my server, machine `B` on port `pb`.

Note that, *`A` and `C` are on the internet*, so in effect, I have to act as a gateway between two machines on the internet (the literature I've found in most firewall docs concerns acting as a gateway *between the internet and your local* network).

### Extras

Machine `B` is running OpenSuse 11.4

### Requirements

My task is to make sure I give machine `C` the service offered by `A` via my server `B`, in such a way that traffic from `A:pa` ends up on `C:pc` and traffic from `C:pc` ends up on `A:pa`.

So, how can I achieve this, say using `iptables` or another Linux / Unix utility? Is it even possible?

### Hypothetical Solution:

Here's an Idea I have in mind, but am not sure it's legit or makes sense:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --source a.a.a.a --source-port pa \
--destination b.b.b.b --destination-port pb -j DNAT --to-destination c.c.c.c:pc
```

and

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --source c.c.c.c --source-port pc \
--destination b.b.b.b --destination-port pb -j DNAT --to-destination a.a.a.a:pa
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that C is connecting to A:pa (it's not quite clear). You need to perform both DNAT and SNAT on B for these connections from C:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s c.c.c.c -d b.b.b.b --dport pb -j DNAT --to-destination a.a.a.a:pa
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d a.a.a.a --dport pa -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Thanks, to make it clearer, surely C wants to connect to A:pa, but can't do it directly, that's why C must connect to B:pb and B:pb acts as a proxy for A:pa. The same applies to A:pa wanting to talk to C:pc.

Comment: @nemesisfixx Do you mean that A *also* needs to connect to C:pc (as in make a TCP connection), or just that packets need to get back from A to C for the C->A connection?

Comment: packets from A need to get to C, and packets from C need to get to A. Only that a direct connection is not possible, thus B must provide the gateway.